# How to Ignore Nested Brackets in a String in Lua?

Tags: string, design-patterns, lua

I have a set of special characters that can be thought of as brackets. When a user encloses some text between these brackets, I simply want the program to replace whatever brackets were used, with `<, >`. So, if `*, *` are the brackets and the string is `"Hello *world*"`, the program should return `"Hello <world>"`.

The problem is I want to avoid nested occurrences of these bracket pairs, and **I only want the program to focus on the outermost pair.** In other words, once an opening bracket is made, treat all of the characters as normal characters until the opening bracket is closed.

For example, if my brackets are `*, *` and `#, #` and my string is `"Hello *wo#rl#d*"`, the program should return: `"Hello <wo#rl#d>"` instead of: `"Hello <wo<rl>d>"`

I've tried using `string.gsub` to find all patterns of text between the defined special characters, but of course, it won't ignore nested occurrences of them.

```lua
local specialChars = {"*", "#", "-"}
local text = "Hello, world. *Won#der#ful* day, -don't- you #th*in*k?#"

for i = 1, #specialChars do
    local bracket = specialChars[i]
    local escBracket = "%" .. bracket

    text = string.gsub(text, escBracket .. "(.-)" .. escBracket, function(content)
        return "<" .. content .. ">"
    end)
end

print(text)
```

The code above should display:

```
"Hello, world. <Won#der#ful> day, <don't> you <th*in*k?>"
```

but instead displays:

```
"Hello, world. <Won<der>ful> day, <don't> you <th<in>k?>"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `text = text:gsub("([%*%#%-])(.-)%1", "<%2>")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you very much! That does exactly what I wanted. Could this also work if I wanted my brackets to be more than one character? i.e, `**, **`?

Comment: No.  But you can replace all multi-character combinations with 1-character items (example of unused characters: `\001`, `\002`, etc.) prior to converting and replace them back after conversion.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Wow, you're a genius. Thank you so much for your help and for the follow-up support.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  I suppose I have one more concern, if it's not asking too much. Now I'm facing a problem where I can't assume the closing bracket will be the same characters as the opening bracket. For example, the case where `[[, ]]` or `&_, _&` are the bracket pairs. For this, I feel like my only option may be to iterate over all the characters and parse the string that way...

Comment: @WillWillington - Are nested brackets of the same type `[[..[[..]]..]]` allowed?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Not for this case, no. That should just return `<..[[..>..]]`. I suppose another way of wording the question could be: Is there a way to find any string of any length, `A`, between some text, and another string of any content or length, `B`, such that `A` and `B` are replaced with `<` and `>` and the text is left in the middle.

Comment: ... for any number of `Aₙ, Bₙ` pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local text = "[[**Hello**, &_world_&.]] &_*Won#der#ful* day_&, **-don't- you** #th*in*k?#"
print(text)

local single_char = "*#-"
-- "o."=open, ".c"=close, "oc"=both open and close
local multi_char = { -- use chars "\1","\2",...,"\6" to start each group
   ["\1o."] = "[[", 
   ["\1.c"] = "]]",  
   ["\2o."] = "&_", 
   ["\2.c"] = "_&",
   ["\3oc"] = "**",
}
for k, v in pairs(multi_char) do
   text = text:gsub(v:gsub("%p", "%%%0"), k)
end
text = text
   :gsub("["..single_char:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."]", "%0oc")
   :gsub("([\1-\6"..single_char:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."])o.(.-)%1.c", "<%2>")
   :gsub("(["..single_char:gsub("%p", "%%%0").."])..", "%1")
   :gsub("[\1-\6]..", multi_char)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
[[**Hello**, &_world_&.]] &_*Won#der#ful* day_&, **-don't- you** #th*in*k?#
<**Hello**, &_world_&.> <*Won#der#ful* day>, <-don't- you> <th*in*k?>
```

Comment: This is great. Again, I very much appreciate the help.